# Neo4j concurrent querying issues

Tags: performance, concurrency, neo4j, locking, neo4j-spatial

I'm running load tests in my production environment and I've found out there's some kind of concurrency issues. I'm running a query that takes (in average) 900ms to return my results. 
What I've seen is: if I run queries with concurrent users using JMeter with a latency lower than 900ms (20 users in 20 secs ramp-up) the response times start increasing in some kind of snowball effect.

Final times are:

```
1   15:39:14.641    Thread Group 1-1    Query   981     Success 31020   948     31
2   15:39:15.041    Thread Group 1-2    Query   1451    Success 31020   1412    30
3   15:39:15.446    Thread Group 1-3    Query   1943    Success 31020   1868    30
4   15:39:15.843    Thread Group 1-4    Query   2367    Success 31020   2333    29
5   15:39:16.244    Thread Group 1-5    Query   2842    Success 31020   2805    56
6   15:39:16.648    Thread Group 1-6    Query   3385    Success 31020   3334    30
7   15:39:17.044    Thread Group 1-7    Query   3890    Success 31020   3857    30
8   15:39:17.444    Thread Group 1-8    Query   4423    Success 31020   4375    29
9   15:39:17.851    Thread Group 1-9    Query   4952    Success 31020   4908    31
10  15:39:18.246    Thread Group 1-10   Query   5447    Success 31020   5409    31
11  15:39:18.650    Thread Group 1-11   Query   5952    Success 31020   5918    30
12  15:39:19.047    Thread Group 1-12   Query   6459    Success 31020   6423    32
13  15:39:19.452    Thread Group 1-13   Query   6994    Success 31020   6952    30
14  15:39:19.854    Thread Group 1-14   Query   7494    Success 31020   7459    30
15  15:39:20.253    Thread Group 1-15   Query   7976    Success 31020   7933    31
16  15:39:20.649    Thread Group 1-16   Query   8476    Success 31020   8424    30
17  15:39:21.055    Thread Group 1-17   Query   9001    Success 31020   8959    30
18  15:39:21.451    Thread Group 1-18   Query   9549    Success 31020   9489    30
19  15:39:21.850    Thread Group 1-19   Query   10057   Success 31020   10020   75
20  15:39:22.255    Thread Group 1-20   Query   10616   Success 31020   10562   28
21  15:39:22.657    Thread Group 1-21   Query   11071   Success 31020   11038   29
22  15:39:23.053    Thread Group 1-22   Query   11620   Success 31020   11583   45
23  15:39:23.453    Thread Group 1-23   Query   12125   Success 31020   12080   30
24  15:39:23.854    Thread Group 1-24   Query   12622   Success 31020   12577   32
25  15:39:24.259    Thread Group 1-25   Query   13141   Success 31020   13099   31
26  15:39:24.661    Thread Group 1-26   Query   13623   Success 31020   13586   29
27  15:39:25.056    Thread Group 1-27   Query   14182   Success 31020   14113   30
28  15:39:25.457    Thread Group 1-28   Query   14769   Success 31020   14616   31
29  15:39:25.855    Thread Group 1-29   Query   15158   Success 31020   15100   34
30  15:39:26.258    Thread Group 1-30   Query   15617   Success 31020   15580   48
31  15:39:26.662    Thread Group 1-31   Query   16095   Success 31020   16063   31
32  15:39:27.058    Thread Group 1-32   Query   16639   Success 31020   16556   32
33  15:39:27.457    Thread Group 1-33   Query   17105   Success 31020   17059   34
34  15:39:27.860    Thread Group 1-34   Query   17614   Success 31020   17573   30
35  15:39:28.262    Thread Group 1-35   Query   18113   Success 31020   18076   30
36  15:39:28.658    Thread Group 1-36   Query   18631   Success 31020   18597   38
37  15:39:29.058    Thread Group 1-37   Query   19088   Success 31020   19045   39
38  15:39:29.458    Thread Group 1-38   Query   19577   Success 31020   19541   31
39  15:39:29.861    Thread Group 1-39   Query   20081   Success 31020   20042   30
40  15:39:30.264    Thread Group 1-40   Query   20611   Success 31020   20556   30
41  15:39:30.660    Thread Group 1-41   Query   21082   Success 31020   21046   30
42  15:39:31.065    Thread Group 1-42   Query   21595   Success 31020   21546   32
43  15:39:31.460    Thread Group 1-43   Query   22080   Success 31020   22033   31
44  15:39:31.862    Thread Group 1-44   Query   22597   Success 31020   22553   33
45  15:39:32.262    Thread Group 1-45   Query   23075   Success 31020   23041   129
46  15:39:32.662    Thread Group 1-46   Query   23586   Success 31020   23549   55
47  15:39:33.062    Thread Group 1-47   Query   24100   Success 31020   24061   31
48  15:39:33.463    Thread Group 1-48   Query   24546   Success 31020   24503   30
49  15:39:33.865    Thread Group 1-49   Query   25053   Success 31020   24991   29
50  15:39:34.265    Thread Group 1-50   Query   25512   Success 31020   25470   30
```

I guess it's some configuration issue.

I've gone through http://neo4j.com/developer/in-production/ to set up my environment properly, it's using an Amazon AWS m3.large instance:

- 7.5Gb. RAM
- 2 core processor
- 4Gb Heap size
- 320 threads max

Can anybody shed some light on this?

**EDIT**

Query is:

```
START station=node:LocationIndex('withinDistance:[51.51766116938769,-0.09774009180783261,8.0]'), user=node(9999) 
MATCH (tt:TimeTable)<--(line:Line)<-[h:HasTrainLine]-station
    WHERE tt.from <= 2100 AND tt.to >= 2100 and tt-[:validOn]->(:Weekday{dow:5})
WITH station, tt, line, user
OPTIONAL MATCH user-[r:isFav]->station 
OPTIONAL MATCH user-[r2:Uses]->line 
WITH station, r, sum(r2.timesUsed) as times, tt 
RETURN station, times, not(r is NULL) as fav 
ORDER BY times DESC, station.name ASC  
SKIP 0 
LIMIT 16
```

**EDITED**

I took a thread dump form the jvm whilst running the load tests -> https://gist.github.com/aabutaleb/1a2cb6d1067bdff96be8

I found something interesting in line [961](https://gist.github.com/aabutaleb/1a2cb6d1067bdff96be8#file-threaddumps-log-L961) which shows Spatial acquiring a write lock, but this doesn't make sense since there're no writings in this query...

```
    0x00007fbb1bce0414  __pthread_cond_wait + 0xc4
0x00007fbb1ae8cadd  _ZN13ObjectMonitor4waitElbP6Thread + 0x9bd
0x00007fbb1acfc378  JVM_MonitorWait + 0x168
0x00007fbb11012d78  * java.lang.Object.wait(long) bci:0 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006058  * java.lang.Object.wait() bci:2 line:503 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006058  * org.neo4j.kernel.impl.locking.community.RWLock.deadlockGuardedWait(javax.transaction.Transaction, org.neo4j.kernel.impl.locking.community.RWLock$TxLockElement, org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.LockType) bci:29 line:551 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006058  * org.neo4j.kernel.impl.locking.community.RWLock.acquireWriteLock(javax.transaction.Transaction) bci:40 line:319 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006058  * org.neo4j.kernel.impl.locking.community.LockManagerImpl.getWriteLock(java.lang.Object, javax.transaction.Transaction) bci:7 line:68 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006058  * org.neo4j.kernel.impl.locking.community.CommunityLockClient.acquireExclusive(org.neo4j.kernel.impl.locking.Locks$ResourceType, long[]) bci:82 line:73 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006706  * org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.LockingStatementOperations.nodeSetProperty(org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelStatement, long, org.neo4j.kernel.api.properties.DefinedProperty) bci:35 line:280 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb110068e1  * org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeSetProperty(long, org.neo4j.kernel.api.properties.DefinedProperty) bci:17 line:545 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb110068e1  * org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object) bci:46 line:254 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006706  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.rtree.RTreeIndex.saveCount() bci:67 line:435 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006058  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.rtree.RTreeIndex.initIndexMetadata() bci:111 line:399 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006058  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.rtree.RTreeIndex.<init>(org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService, org.neo4j.graphdb.Node, org.neo4j.gis.spatial.rtree.EnvelopeDecoder, int) bci:54 line:63 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006058  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.LayerRTreeIndex.<init>(org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService, org.neo4j.gis.spatial.Layer, int) bci:15 line:49 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006058  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.LayerRTreeIndex.<init>(org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService, org.neo4j.gis.spatial.Layer) bci:5 line:45 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006058  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.DefaultLayer.initialize(org.neo4j.gis.spatial.SpatialDatabaseService, java.lang.String, org.neo4j.graphdb.Node) bci:158 line:281 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006706  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.DefaultLayer.makeLayerInstance(org.neo4j.gis.spatial.SpatialDatabaseService, java.lang.String, org.neo4j.graphdb.Node, java.lang.Class) bci:22 line:251 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006233  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.DefaultLayer.makeLayerFromNode(org.neo4j.gis.spatial.SpatialDatabaseService, org.neo4j.graphdb.Node) bci:64 line:219 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006233  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.SpatialDatabaseService.getLayer(java.lang.String) bci:84 line:111 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006233  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.SpatialDatabaseService.getOrCreateLayer(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class, java.lang.String) bci:16 line:202 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006233  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.SpatialDatabaseService.getOrCreateEditableLayer(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) bci:34 line:175 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006233  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.indexprovider.LayerNodeIndex.<init>(java.lang.String, org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService, java.util.Map) bci:187 line:97 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006058  * org.neo4j.gis.spatial.indexprovider.SpatialIndexImplementation.nodeIndex(java.lang.String, java.util.Map) bci:10 line:47 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb110068e1  * org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.getOrCreateNodeIndex(java.lang.String, java.util.Map) bci:39 line:318 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006233  * org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.forNodes(java.lang.String, java.util.Map) bci:7 line:302 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006233  * org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.forNodes(java.lang.String) bci:3 line:294 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb110068e1  * org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_1.TransactionBoundQueryContext$NodeOperations.indexQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object) bci:16 line:172 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb110068e1  * org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.spi.DelegatingOperations.indexQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object) bci:7 line:128 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006233  * org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_1$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$super$indexQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object) bci:3 line:142 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006233  * org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$indexQuery$1.apply() bci:12 line:142 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006233  * org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$indexQuery$1.apply() bci:1 line:142 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11374194  * org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_1$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$translateException(scala.Function0) bci:1 line:149 (Compiled frame)
* org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations.indexQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object) bci:14 line:142 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb110068e1  * org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.spi.DelegatingOperations.indexQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object) bci:7 line:128 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb110068e1  * org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.builders.EntityProducerFactory$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ExecutionContext, org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.QueryState) bci:24 line:67 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006233  * org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.builders.EntityProducerFactory$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) bci:9 line:65 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb118019e4  * org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.builders.EntityProducerFactory$$anon$1.apply(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ExecutionContext, org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.QueryState) bci:6 line:35 (Compiled frame)
* org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.builders.EntityProducerFactory$$anon$1.apply(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) bci:9 line:34 (Compiled frame)
* org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.matching.MonoDirectionalTraversalMatcher.findMatchingPaths(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.QueryState, org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ExecutionContext) bci:6 line:45 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb110068e1  * org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.TraversalMatchPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ExecutionContext) bci:14 line:35 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007fbb11006233  * org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.TraversalMatchPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(java.lang.Object) bci:5 line:32 (Interpreted frame)
```

However, no locks seems to appear when I remove the geospatial statement from the query. https://gist.github.com/aabutaleb/e3d6b1c72644d330cc82

Comment: what does the query in question do? Please paste your code.

Comment: Which neo4j version, what kind of heap? 320 threads is not sensible for a box with 2 processors, it will just backpressure

Comment: How do you execute the queries? Are you using the transactional http endpoint? Keep-Alive?

Comment: Use a rel-type from line to time-table, lookup the weekday upfront too and add that to the match

Comment: Version 2.1.1, both maximum and initial heaps at 4Gb. You're right. It doesn't ever use more than 75 threads and never more than 500Mb heap. Using newrelic to monitor. I'm just testing boundaries to find out the problem.

Comment: Using Rest-API with Spring-data for our API. But this metrics come from posting the query directly on the Rest-API from JMeter load tests (same enpoint but without the latency of our API)

Comment: @MichaelHunger Do you think using --> instead of rel-types can affect the performance in this situation?

Comment: Might @PeterNeubauer know something about this issue?

Comment: Seems to be related to this issue, still open in spatial contrib repo https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial/issues/145